# ﬁnding a ﬁxed-point ˆ x∈R for the function

Tags: numerical-methods

[image]

I don't know how to verify this function if I can't use the Banach-Caccioppoli Contraction Principle. Please help

Comment: Try solving the equation $g(x)=x$.

Answer (score 0):

$g$ has a fixed point $\hat x$ if and only if $g(\hat x) = \hat x$, hence
$$
g(\hat x) = \hat x \iff 1 + \hat x - \left(\frac{\hat x}{2} \right)^3 = \hat x \iff 1-\left(\frac{\hat x}{2} \right)^3 = 0
$$

Can you continue from here? Does exist $\hat x$? Is it unique?

Answer (score 0):

A fixed point for $g(x)$ should be a point $\hat{x}$ with the property that $g(\hat{x})=x$. I.e., we want to solve $$1+x-\frac{1}{8}x^3=x$$ for $x$. We rewrite this to $$1-\frac{1}{8}x^3=0,$$ and finally to $$x^3=-8.$$ It is clear that this last equation has $-2$ as its only solution.

Comment: thank you it is very clear.could you also please help me for part c

Comment: Unfortunately not.